# Autofilter method of range class. Not the usual

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have an error occurring, which seems to plague many different people in many different ways. In my case, my code works, but the runtime error popping up after each change is very annoying.

My code is below:

```
Public Sub Filter_Sheets()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim comboBox As ControlFormat

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set comboBox = .Worksheets(9).Shapes("Drop Down 229").ControlFormat
        For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
            .Worksheets(i).UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=comboBox.List(comboBox.ListIndex)
        Next
    End With 
End Sub
```

The line that is failing is`.Worksheets(i).UsedRange.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=comboBox.List(comboBox.ListIndex)`

I have tried a different things for Range and Worksheets, along with the line above the bugged code. I have tried putting quotes around the criteria, nothing has yet solved the bug.

Anyone got any idea?

Comment: Are you sure every sheet has at least 15 columns of data?

Comment: try adding `theCriteria = comboBox.List(comboBox.ListIndex)` and passing `theCriteria` into `Criteria1` argument.

Comment: may be not the culprit in this particular case, but change `Worksheets.Count` to `.Worksheets.Count` and have it reference the same workbook (i.e. `ThisWorkbook`) whose worksheets you seem to want to loop through

Comment: Some good ideas here guys, not all sheets do have 15 columns of data, only the first 7, 8 and 9 do not, but I'm not sure how to tell it to stop loping at 7. Referencing ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count didn't change anything. Neither did theCritera, I got the same error with both.

Comment: Ok, fix found. Changing {For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count} to {For i = 1 To 7} has done the trick. I had been trying to get it working with {For i = 1 To Worksheets("Sheet7")} unsuccessfully too.

Comment: @AlexanderRhodes, out of curiosity, what value did `Worksheets.Count` return?

Comment: 10 which is correct, but I only wanted to filter data in the first 7.